# Memory exhausted using an array in a nested loop

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, out-of-memory, nested-loops

This is the error I'm getting.

> Fatal Error: Allowed memory size exhausted.

I'm fetching arrays containing a date `from` and a date `till`. I'm trying to get all the dates in between and add them to a new array. Apparently nested loops and multi-arrays are exhausting.

I need a less exhausting way of getting all the dates.

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM reservate
          ORDER BY from";
$result = $connect->query($query);

$reservations = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $reservations[] = $row;
    }
}

$connect->close();

//AVAILABILITY CHECK
$nonAvailable = array();
foreach($reservations as $reservation){
    $from = $reservation['from'];
    $till = $reservation['till'];

    while($from <= $till){
        $nonAvailable[] = $from;
        $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days"));
    }
}
```

Comment: While I think @robbmj has spotted the issue, how large are these date ranges? What are they used for? If you are just finding the non available dates to use in a further query then it would be possible to return just the non available dates as a result from an SQL query.

Comment: the dates i tested ranged around 8 days. Eventually it will have to deal with date ranges to maybe a max of 2 months. As for the sql, i havent put much effort in too learning more than the basics just yet.

What i eventually aim to do is: I have a generated calendar and i want to have the nonAvailable dates highlighted. I more or less had it working but had to make some changes.

Comment: I will write an extra answer to give you some ideas, although the already accepted answer is a perfect answer to your actual question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you made an infinite loop<sup>1</sup>.

```
// if $till is in the future, this is an infinite loop
while($from <= $till){
    // appending the same value of $from on each iteration
    $nonAvailable[] = $from;
    // as $from never changes value
    $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days"));
}
```

Add `1` day to the current value of `$from`

```
while ($from <= $till){
     $nonAvailable[] = $from;
     // add 1 day to $from
     $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from, "+1 days"));
}
```

**There are still a few improvements that can be made:**

- In the following example the entire table is not copied to the
     `reservation` array and we are only retrieving the columns we need
     from the table.
- Comparing `integers` instead of `strings`.
- Adding `1` day to `$from` manually rather then relying on `strtotime` to do it.

```
$query = "SELECT from, till
          FROM reservate
          ORDER BY from";
$result = $connect->query($query);

$nonAvailable = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $from = strtotime($row['from']);
        $till = strtotime($row['till']);

        while ($from <= $till) {
            $nonAvailable[] = date('Y-m-d', $from);
            $from += 60*60*24;
        }
    }
}

$connect->close();
```

It is likely that this algorithm can be made much more efficient. For example do you need an exhaustive list of each day something is reserved? If not then just the start date and end date should suffice.

---

<sub>1 *Given enough time and memory the loop would exit as `strtotime("+1 days")` would eventually return a value greater than `$till`.*</sub>

Comment: @iDobbler, no worries, I'm happy to help. I updated the answer with a few more tips that you may be interested in, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Today is not a bright day for me xD. I took a whole new approach and made a different function and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing this, using just a single query.

This takes your reservation table and cross joins it with a couple of sub queries that get ranges of numbers. Each get the numbers 0 to 9, and one is used as units and one as tens. Combined together they give you the numbers 0 to 99 (so 99 day range).

The WHERE clause just checks that the from date (van) plus the number of days (from 0 to 99) is less than or equal to the to date (tot). Hence a room (I am assuming multiple rooms, or some other item that is being booked out) is put out with each date where it is booked:-

```
SELECT room, DATE_ADD(van, INTERVAL (tens.i * 10 + units.i) DAY) AS non_available
FROM reservate
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
WHERE DATE_ADD(van, INTERVAL (tens.i * 10 + units.i) DAY) <= tot
ORDER BY room, non_available
```

SQL fiddle example:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83054/1

You could use a table of integers instead of the 2 sub queries.